# Android : Volley ServerError response code 400

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to send json data to fcm server url,  When i send a notification from fcm, i get the default notification and my custom notification is not shown. I want to implement this so that my `onMessageReceived()` gets called. I get this error each time i try to send.

```
04-11 13:39:22.244 21208-26145/com.myapp E/Volley: [28124] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/
04-11 13:39:22.244 21208-21208/com.myapp E/!_@@_Errors--: com.android.volley.ServerError
```

This is what i have,

```
private void sendFCMPush() {

    final String Legacy_SERVER_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key);
    String msg = "this is test message,.,,.,.";
    String title = "my title";
    String token = "MY_TOKEN";

    JSONObject obj = null;
    JSONObject objData = null;
    JSONObject dataobjData = null;

    try {
        obj = new JSONObject();
        objData = new JSONObject();

        objData.put("body", msg);
        objData.put("title", title);

        dataobjData = new JSONObject();
        dataobjData.put("text", msg);
        dataobjData.put("title", title);

        obj.put("to", token);
        //obj.put("priority", "high");

        obj.put("notification", objData);
        obj.put("data", dataobjData);
        Log.d("!_@rj@_@@_PASS:>", obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, API_URL_FCM, obj,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("!_@@_SUCESS", response + "");
                }
            },
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("!_@@_Errors--", error + "");
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "key=" + Legacy_SERVER_KEY);
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    int socketTimeout = 1000 * 60;// 60 seconds
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

I've been trying different ways but none of them worked for me. please help me out.

Comment: I think its a issue with your json as it cannot be parsed. See the detailed error. or post the completely error

Comment: can you help me with the json, i am sending a basic message, title, body and to...

Comment: Post your complete error code

Comment: I am getting two errors only

Comment: see this how to send the json : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages